# How do I filter so that I am only seeing the selected states?

Tags: r

Having issues understanding why R wont compute my syntax. Given the sample df:

```
Name              Birth.State                 height    `Birth.State == "New Jersey"`
  <chr>             <chr>                       <chr>     <lgl>                        
1 George Washington "     Virginia"             74 inches FALSE                        
2 John Adams        "            Massachusetts" 67 inches FALSE                        
3 Thomas Jefferson  "      Virginia"            75 inches FALSE                        
4 James Madison     "         Virginia"         64 inches FALSE                        
5 James Monroe      "          Virginia"        72 inches FALSE
```

My goal is to just have data of presidents from New Jersey, I've tried the following but have been having issues.

```
str_detect(c$Birth.State, pattern = "New Jersey")
filter(c,grep('New Jersey',Birth.State))
parse_character(c$Birth.State)
is.character(c$Birth.State)
```

Comment: Have you tried the `dplyr` package? Then it would be `df %>% filter(Birth.State == "New Jersey")`

Comment: Do not use `c` as an object, it is a base function in R

Comment: @ViníciusFélix didnt know that, thank you!

Comment: You have leading blanks in `Birth.State`. You can get rid of it with `trimws` and then use `filter` or `subset`, `grep`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demonstrating suggestions in the comments:

```
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(name = "George Washington",
           state = "     Virginia")
```

No exact match because of white spaces

```
"Virginia" %in% df$state
#> [1] FALSE
```

Use pattern matching

```
str_detect(df$state, pattern = "Virginia")
#> [1] TRUE
df[str_detect(df$state, pattern = "Virginia"),"name"]
#> [1] "George Washington"

grepl("Virginia", df$state)
#> [1] TRUE
df[grepl("Virginia", df$state),"name"]
#> [1] "George Washington"
```

Or remove white space:

```
df$state2 <- trimws(df$state)
"Virginia" %in% df$state2
#> [1] TRUE
df[df$state2 == "Virginia", "name"]
#> [1] "George Washington"
```

Created on 2021-09-23 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)